# cluster.properties file getting jira.node.id ID automatically, like the hostname

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I would like to edit the **cluster.properties** file to the parameter **jira.node.id** gets an ID automatically, for example the hostname.

It is possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

Basically I created a bash script to add automatically the hostname in the file. Something like this:

*HOST=$HOSTNAME
JIRANODE="jira.node.id = "$HOST
sed -i "2s/.*/$JIRANODE/" /var/atlassian/application-data/jira/cluster.properties*

This bash is executed in every reboot via cron.